# Function point count given source code

Tags: java

Given the source code of a program, how do I analyze it and count the function points within it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you define "function points"? Are you referring to the number of methods declared in the file or the number of places where a particular method ("function") is being called?

Comment: Also, it would help to know what IDE you're using - several of the more modern Java IDEs have analysis or metrics built-in or available as plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this [tutorial](http://www.devdaily.com/FunctionPoints/) on FPA of interest.  Personally, I don't put much stock in this estimation method.  From my perspective it attempts to provide a precise estimate in for things that have been shown repeatedly to not be precisely measurable.  I much prefer [planning poker](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/topics/planning-poker) or something similar that tries to group things within a similar order of magnitude and provide an estimate based on your previous estimations for similarly sized stories.

If you're doing this for a class, simply follow the rules given in the text book and crank out the answer.  If you're really intending to try this as a software development estimation method, my advice is to simplify the process rather than make it more complex.  I would  imagine that members of the International Function Point User Group (yes, there is one), will disagree.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks so much for that information tvanfosson! And yes, I am doing this for a class and the reason I am having such a hard time is because the teacher simply didn't give us the tools to produce a count! He has left it up to us to figure that out and it has been most difficult trying to figure this out. Your information is very much appreciated and I will take note of it! Thanks!!

Comment: planning poker has an entirely different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

With a code analysis tool. If you want to write one yourself, you might want to start with cglib or ASM.